# Geneos: How to get last value from dataview column?

Tags: dataview, geneos, itrs

The FKM dataview looks like this:
[image]

I would like to store the last value (marked blue) under a variable and pass it to an email alert. Right now I have a defined path alias (see pic) which I grab in the rule with:

```
set $(trigger) path "triggerDetails" value
```

[image]

but this grabs the null value from the row where the "FAIL" status is detected (marked red). I need the last element from the array, unfortunately I have no idea how to access it. Any helpful suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be going about it the wrong way.

If you want to have an email Action to contain the last trigger message, you can get the sampler to put the details in the status column.

**Status Column Before:**

```
FAIL
```

**Status Column After:**

```
FAIL: 2018-05-03 10:06:06,907|ERROR|Last Log Message
```

This screenshot shows where to enable this functionality.

[image: Last Trigger]

From the Help Pages:

**display > lastTriggerInStatus**

When FKM detects a new trigger, the file status is to include the file line of the latest-detected trigger. This setting enables users to disable this behaviour (by setting the value to false), so that the file status is displayed only as FAIL or WARNING.

Mandatory: No

Default: true